# Corona SDK use accelerometer without event listener

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk, game-physics

I want to write a method in my game which only uses the "accelerometer gravity" at a set point in time, so I don't want to have an event listener calling a method which uses the accelerometer as an event all the time

I want to do something like this

```
local function exampleFunction ()
     if accelerometer.xGravity > exampleValue then
          print("success")
     end
end
```

but unfortunately you can't just call accelerometer as if it were a variable.

what do I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the Corona Sample code that has accelerometer events.  It prints out the x,y,z coordinates in a Runtime listener.  Check out that sample, but be warned, the API for accelerometer in Corona changes depending upon the device. Some Android devices aren't as responsive as others.